# Stationary point question?

Tags: calculus

Find the coordinates of the two points on curve   $y=2x^3+3x^2-36x+9$ at which the tangents to the curve are $parallel$ to the x-axis. 
Hence determine the equations of these two tangents,
Help i'm stuck with this one.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and then solve  $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$, since our desired lines must have slope zero, which is the slope of the x-axis (and hence of the lines parallel to it).

Solve the equation. You'll then have the x-coordinates of each of two points: $x_1, x_2$. Evaluate $y$ at each of these values of $x$. That will give you  $y_1, y_2$, respectively.

Since the lines are horizontal (slope is zero), you'll have two equations $$y = y_1, \quad y = y_2$$